# How to get text after forward slashes (up until next forward slash or end of string)?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a URL cleaned up to look like this:

```
/foo/bar
```

I tried this:

```
preg_match('#([a-zA-z0-9]+)#', $path, $matches);
```

But $matches is output as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /foo
    [1] => foo
)
```

What regex can be used (i.e. with `preg_match()`) to get `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: Use `explode()`, no regex needed

Comment: @Michael that's a *really* good point, but I would like to figure out how to get this working since I've been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can best use explode for this:

```
print_r(explode('/',ltrim('/foo/bar','/')));
```

But if you want to do it with regex (for this very bad) just use `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/','/foo/bar', $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
```

For more information look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php
Both result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP explode():

```
$arr = explode('/', substr($str,1) );
```

returns

```
Array(
   [0] = 'foo';
   [1] = 'bar'
)
```